# GPflow multi-output support for SGPR

Tags: gpflow

GPflow seems to only support multi-output for SVGP. Is it possible to use this multi-output support for other models (e.g. SGPR)? For example:

```py
kernel = mk.SharedIndependentMok(gpf.kernels.RBF(D), P)
feature = features.InducingPoints(X[:M,...].copy())
m = gpf.models.SGPR(X, Y, kernel, feature)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an identified issue (https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/1209), that currently has comparatively low priority for the GPflow core developers - but we'd be very happy for you to join us and contribute features! There is now [a public GPflow slack](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow#slack-workspace) for ease of discussion.

Comment: I am interested in contributing. Who do I contact?

Comment: @tadejk Reply to the issue, join the slack channel... :)